# Firefox Extension : onProgressChange called multiple times

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to capture a page load event while developing a extension for firefox. I am using ProgressListeners for this. I cannot use the onLocation change event because it fires an event every time the user switches the tab. I just want to log every new page he has visited. OnProgressChange works for me, but this is fired multiple times per page. How do I log this for one entry per page. Is there any other event I need to listen to ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

`onProgressChange` is used for notifications about progress, so of course it's called multiple times.

You see `onLocationChange` when the user switches tabs because you attach the progress listener to the tabbrowser, not to an individual tab.

You could try [listening to (progress) events on all tabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Listening_to_events_on_all_tabs) -- start by dumping all events you get and pick either `onLocationChange` or `onStateChange` depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture page loads by attaching a `DOMContentLoaded` listener to the `appcontent` element in every chrome window. Like this:

```
var LoadTest = {
    // chrome window loaded
    onload: function() {
        var appContent = document.getElementById("appcontent");
        appContent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
            alert("page loaded");
        }, true);
    }
};

window.addEventListener("load", LoadTest.onload, false);
```

The `LoadTest.onload` method will be executed when a new chrome window loads. The function listening for `DOMContentLoaded` will load every time a page is visited or a tab is opened.